# GCE Windows startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am facing a strange problem where my `windows-startup-script-ps1` is not running at startup as per [official link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances). This corresponds to a PowerShell script as the name indicates. Having looked further into Serial Port logs I found that the error is:

> The term 'gs://mybucket/metadata.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
> that the path is correct and try again.

I tried giving it the Cloud Storage API object path but it's still getting this error. My Compute Engine VM has read-only Cloud Storage access and I verified it by running `gsutil` inside my Compute Engine VM. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

```
Function Write-SerialPort ([string] $message) {
    $port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,one
    $port.open()
    $port.WriteLine($message)
    $port.Close()
}

Write-SerialPort ("STARTING GCE Startup Script")

$IsInstalled = ((Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server).installed)
if ($isinstalled -eq $false){
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools -IncludeAllSubFeature -Confirm:$false
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45
    Write-SerialPort ("Installation Complete")
}
else{
    Write-SerialPort ("IIS Server (WebServer) is already installed")
}

Write-SerialPort ("FINISHING GCE Startup Script")
```

Comment: You want to check the access and existence of `gs://mybucket/metadata.ps1` before using it.

Comment: Yes I can access bucket inside this compute VM. gsutil ls give me results

Comment: yeah so if I do gsutil ls inside this VM, I can see the contents of mt bucket. what code should I share, powershell script ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added PS script in the question

Comment: I dont' see mention of 'gs://mybucket/metadata.ps1' in your script.

Comment: This keyword you have to put as metadata while creating GCE. it is not a part of PS script

Comment: ..... then add in the post your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could test on my end, it looks like you're adding the Cloud Storage path for the PowerShell script in the [windows-startup-script-ps1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#using-a-local-startup-script-file) metadata key, which is meant for **local** startup scripts that have previously been added to the VM's image, instead of the [windows-startup-script-url](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script) key that supports GCS objects:

> $ gcloud compute instances create your-windows-instance --scopes storage-ro --metadata windows-startup-script-**url**=gs://mybucket/metadata.ps1

Comment: yes that correct , I was able to use  windows-startup-script-url  and it worked. Didnt post the answer myself but marking this as correct for others.